# OnEditingStarted raise two time in iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, xamarin.ios, uisearchbar

I use below codes in my monotuch iOS application for creating a location search mechanism:

```
    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
                    NavigationItem .TitleView = LocationSearchBar ;
LocationSearchBar .OnEditingStarted      += delegate {

                    if(lSAutoCompleteScreen ==null)
                        lSAutoCompleteScreen = new LSAutoCompleteScreen ();
                    lSAutoCompleteScreen .DefaultText = LocationSearchBar .Text;
                        this.NavigationController .PushViewController (lSAutoCompleteScreen,true  );

                };
}
```

at first time, codes works right. When user start editing the search bar, app shows `lSAutoCompleteScreen`. User search and after search user back to the main view. But the problem is now. When you start editing again. Now the `OnEditingStarted` event fires two time! so app try to add `lSAutoCompleteScreen` to the  `NavigationController` two times.  On the second time that he try to add app will crash.because adding a viewcontroller that already there are in the stack is not valid.

So the question is that why should this event fires two time? And why just in the iOS7 the event fire two times. In the iOS6 it just fires one time.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding a handler to OnEditingStarted every time your View is loaded.  Try assigning the handler in the class constructor instead so it is only assigned once.

Comment: When I debug and trace the code. the assignment just calls one time but the event fires two times

Comment: Also when I tried to assign the delgate on the constructor, it face with error null object. I think because the location search bar has been defined in the xib.

Comment: I have some other delegate assignment on the ViewDidLoad but only this method fires two times

Comment: I didn't read your code closely enough - I assumed that the event was on your class, not a sub-object.  It's possible this is a bug you should file with Xamarin.